# How do I make it so the it doesnt round off the currency?

Tags: c#, decimal

I've trying to build a simple tip calculator and get and EXACT value of what the tip should be. I've finished most of it but I'm struggling with finding the exact two numbers after the decimal place because it keeps rounding them off. Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project01LEA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lyndsee Armstrong\nCSIS 1400\nProject #1");
        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //define variables
            const double POOR = 0.10;
            const double AVERAGE = 0.15;
            const double EXCELLENT = 0.20;

            double mealAmount = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

            double doubledPoor = Convert.ToInt32(POOR * mealAmount);
            double doubledAverage = Convert.ToInt32(AVERAGE * mealAmount);
            double doubledExcellent = Convert.ToInt32(EXCELLENT * mealAmount);

            string outStr = string.Format("{0:C2}", doubledPoor);
            string outStr1 = string.Format("{0:C2}", doubledAverage);
            string outStr2 = string.Format("{0:C2}", doubledExcellent);

            textBox2.Text = outStr;
            textBox3.Text = outStr1;
            textBox4.Text = outStr2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tag language when you show code (it helps people find your question and it also affects the syntax highlighting). I've added the c# tag for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `Convert.ToInt32` - that changes your floating point value to an integer value, and integers don't hold fractional values. If you eliminate those lines, this should work exactly as you want (the string formatting looks correct).